# Delete folders with files inside in FTP server with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to delete folders and files of my ftp server with PHP but when a folder has files inside, i can't delete the  folder and all his content. I'm using the function ftp_rmdir to delete folders.I leave the code below.

```
//Connect
echo "Connecting to ".$ftp_host." via FTP...";


$conn = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_host);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);

//
//Enable PASV ( Note: must be done after ftp_login() )
//
$mode = ftp_pasv($conn, TRUE);

//Login OK ?
if ((!$conn) || (!$login) || (!$mode))
{
   die("FTP connection has failed !");
}
echo "<br />Login Ok.<br />";

//
//Now run ftp_nlist()
//
$file_list = ftp_nlist($conn, "/clients/john/files");

foreach ($file_list as $file)
{
    echo "<br>".$file;

    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        ftp_delete($conn,$file);
    }
    else
    {
        ftp_rmdir($conn,$file);
    }


}

//close
ftp_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir

The directory to delete. This must be either an absolute or relative path to an empty directory.

Maybe you can connect via ssh to your server?